# Laravel symlink 403

Tags: php, laravel, apache, server

I created a symlink using `php artisan storage:link` on a remote server (Siteground; Site Tools). This created the necessary symlink between `somesite/public_html/uploads` and `somesite/storage/app/public/uploads`.

I am unable to access any files wrt this symlink e.g. `https://xxx.info/uploads/users/someimage.jpg` and am served a 403. The symlink definitely works as without it `uploads/users/someimage.jpg` gives me a 404.

`public_html/images/somefile.jpg` and `public_html/assets/somecss.css` works as expected. I am using the default laravel .htaccess in the `public_html` folder ([changed laravel from `public`](https://medium.com/@pixelvars/laravel-change-public-html-to-public-html-the-right-way-496431aed94); but don't think that has anything to do with it).

[image: sym link seems good]

Filesystems config: https://pastebin.com/ftcDeQWv

Comment: Could you add your `filesystems.php` config file on the question?

Comment: @ElektaKode done deal.

Comment: Turn on `artisan tinker` and try evaulate `public_path();`.

Comment: already checked. works fine `public_path('uploads')` gives me `/home/customer/www/xxx.info/public_html/uploads` and `storage_path('app/public/uploads')` gives me`/home/customer/www/xxx.info/storage/app/public/uploads`

Comment: Maybe the problem with file permission?

Comment: 755 on the directory for `users` and file perms seem ok too

Answer (score 0):

Mucking around I fixed it by deleting the symlink via ssh with `rm uploads` and adding a symlink with `ln -s ../storage/app/public/uploads uploads` while in the `public_html` folder. Idk why this worked but it did.